# Peek on MSMQIntegrationBinding

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf

I am attempting to bind to a non-transactional MSMQ queue using `MSMQIntegrationBinding`. What I want to be able to do is to peek at the message, and then if conditions are right, go ahead and process it. But, if conditions are not right, I want to leave the message on the queue.

I came upon `ReceiveContextEnabled=True`, but have seen very little documentation or tutorials on how to actually use this.  I am hosting the WCF service library through a Windows Service. However, when I open my host, I get an error like:

> The contract `IWMInTranslator_Service_MSMQ` has at least one operation annotated with `ReceiveContextEnabledAttribute`, but the binding used for the contract endpoint at address `msmq.formatname:DIRECT=OS:CCNU404CCH5%5Cprivate$%5Cwmintranslateque` does not support required binding property 'IReceiveContextSettings'. Please ensure that the binding used for the contract supports the ReceiveContext capability.

If I change it to a transactional queue it seems to work, but I dont want to do this.  Can anybody help?  I create my endpoints and bindings via code (not through app.config). If there are some properties somewhere I can change that would be great!

Thanks,

:) David